# NullPointerException - why?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception. And i have used the long text data type in the ms access table to for date and description

```
 try
         {
         int z1=1,z2=2;
             String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the date(DD/MM/YEAR)");
         String s1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter data into your dairy");
         pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(" INSERT  INTO  Table2(date,description) values(?,?)");
         pstmt.setString(z1, s);
         pstmt.setString(z2, s1);
         pstmt.executeUpdate();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data enterd successfully");
         update1();
         close();
         }

         catch(Exception e1)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Insertion failed.This date may already exist or may be some other error");
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR:"+e1.getMessage());

         }
```

I have used data type long text for date and description in the ms access table.

Comment: Can you post the error message ?

Comment: Did you establish database connection?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace error?

Comment: yes i have made the database connection.

Comment: please post error stack trace and code part where you open a connection...

Comment: the error message is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Print full stack trace... Do s and s1 have values or are they null (try hardcode s and s1 and check if you still get same error)?

Comment: conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:des","","");               stmt=(Statement) conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

Comment: The `null` variable is probably `pstmt` or `conn` the other ones can't be `null`

Comment: catch(Exception e1)
      {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Insertion failed.This date may already exist or may be some other error");
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR:"+e1.getMessage());
       
      }

Comment: Pls don't post code/stacktrace as comment but edit your original post (OP).

Comment: okk. i have edited the original code

Comment: Your title should be brief but descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the only possible `null` variable can be `conn` all the other variables are instantiated using **literals** or using **methods that don't return `null`** (they will throw exceptions if something is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by

```
int z1=1,z2=2;  
String s="14/04/2015";  
String s1="test";  
if ( conn != null ) {
    pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(" INSERT  INTO  Table2(date,description) values(?,?)");
    if ( pstmt != null ) {
        pstmt.setString(z1, s);
        pstmt.setString(z2, s1);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    else {
        System.out.printl("pstmt is null!");
    }
}
else {
    System.out.printl("conn is null!");
}
```

And copy the output here.

Comment: the output is conn is null.